# TFS variables across multiple build definitions

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, build-definition

How can I define variables in Team Foundation Server 2015 which are available across multiple build definitions for one project?

This is needed for a build number which is incremented every build and must be unique across multiple build definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the build ID is unique, instead of defining variables across multiple build definitions, you can simply specify the `Build number format` to `$(date:yyyyMMdd).$(BuildId)`, check the screenshot below:

[image]

In this way, you'll get increased build number in multiple build definition:

[image]